# SSRS - Count elements in a delimited string

Tags: reporting-services

Say I have this string: "1/r/5/dfg/998".  There are five elements delimited by a "/".  I'm looking for the simplest way to count the number of elements in that string in SSRS and would prefer not to write a custom code function.

I know in SSRS split will make an array out of this string and I can use GetUpperBound(0) like this:

split("1/r/5/dfg/998","/").GetUpperBound(0)

The problem is this returns 4 not 5.  If there was a "/" at the end of the string it would return 5.  So I need to check for that and add 0 or 1 like so:

split("1/r/5/dfg/998","/").GetUpperBound(0) + iif(right("1/r/5/dfg/998",1) = "/",0,1)

That will give me 5.  Is there a simpler way to do this?  I wish I could just do

count(split("1/r/5/dfg/998","/"))

but that gives me an error.  Thanks for any suggestions!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just found it while googling and trying different things:

split("1/r/5/dfg/998","/").Length

That's perfect!

Comment: You can mark your own response as the answer to help others with this issue in the future.